# Статическая переменная в методе класса одна для всех объектов класса?

Tags: c++

Статическая переменная в методе класса одна для всех объектов класса?

Comment: Да, одна для всех объектов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да. Статическая переменная класса одна на всех экземляры.
Подробнее о статических переменных C++: [Static (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1sb61xd.aspx)